# Protractor Config : Error on calling Suties for testing non-Angularjs web

Tags: angularjs, protractor

When I test using protractor testing on Non-Angullarjs website, I try to call one specific case, so I use --suite example_A, it will run example A test case,however, after example_A is completed, it will run example_B too.
My config for suite is like this :

```
suites: {
           example_A : "../test_case/homepage/example_A.js",
           example_B : "../test_case/homepage/example_B.js"
    },
```

is it a bug or protractor just doesn't support non-angular website well?

Comment: Hmmmm... I'm not able to reproduce on Protractor 2.1.0. What version are you running?

Comment: $protractor --version
Version 2.1.0
mine is 2.1.0 too

Answer (score 0):

While I can't reproduce this, I'm guessing that your default `specs` property in your config is set to run all tests? I.e. it's defaulting back to the config for which testes to run. If so, try removing that from your config and run again?

You should also be using the "=" when running your tests. Eg. `--suite=example_A`, but I tried this, but still couldn't reproduce the problem. Still...

Comment: i didn't include any ``specs`` in my config, that's why i feel it is super weird.

Comment: all my other test work in other protractor config file work well (the ``suite`` is working right), but the one on non-Angular web doesn't work